# error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>



/*GENERAL*/
#define GLOBAL  0.3
#define PERSONAL 0.3
#define INERT  0.3
#define DELAY  100

/*SWARM*/
#define N   60 //NUmber of agents
#define K   200 //Number of moves
int i = 0; 

/* LIMITS */
#define Xmin  -4
#define Xmax  6
#define Ymin  -4
#define Ymax  6

double velocity[N][2];
double swarm[N][2];
double BestPers[N][3];
double BestGlob[3];


float Lrand(float min, float max)
{
    return (min + ((rand() % 10000) / 1e4) * (max - min));
}

void init() //Generate initial positions and directions
{
  for (int i = 0; i <N; i++);
    {
        swarm[i][0] = Lrand(Xmin, Xmax);
        swarm[i][1] = Lrand(Ymin, Ymax);
        velocity[i][0] = Lrand(-1, 1);
        velocity[i][1] = Lrand(-1, 1);
        BestPers[i][2] = 100000;
    }
    BestGlob[3] = 100000;
}

void MoveWasp() //Moves the whole wasp
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)
        {
            velocity[i][a] = INERT * velocity[i][a] +
                Lrand(-1, 1) * GLOBAL * (BestGlob[a] - swarm[i][a]) +
                Lrand(-1, 1) * PERSONAL * (BestPers[i][a] - swarm[i][a]);
            swarm[i][a] = swarm[i][a] + velocity[i][a];
        }
    }
}

int chkBrd(int i) //Verifies agent's position
{
    if ((Xmin <= swarm[i][0]) && (swarm[i][0] <= Xmax) && (Ymin <= swarm[i][1]) && (swarm[i][1] <= Ymax))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

double calculate(int i)
{
    double f;
    double a = swarm[i][0], b = swarm[i][1];
    f = (a * a + b * b);
    // f = - 0.1 * fabs(1 - b) - 0.1 * fabs(1 - a) - j0(a * a + b * b);
    // f = a * sin(4 * a) + 1.1 * b * sin(2 * b);
    return f;
}

void checkBP(int i, double a)
{
    if (a < BestPers[i][2])
    {
        BestPers[i][2] = a;
        BestPers[i][1] = swarm[i][1];
        BestPers[i][0] = swarm[i][0];
    }
}

void checkBG(int i, double a)
{
    if (a < BestGlob[2])
    {
        BestGlob[2] = a;
        BestGlob[1] = swarm[i][1];
        BestGlob[0] = swarm[i][0];
    }
}


void display(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << "\t" << BestGlob[0] << "\t" << BestGlob[1] << "\t" << BestGlob[2] << "\n";
}

void go()
{
    double a;
    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (chkBrd(i))
            {
                a = calculate(i);
                checkBP(i, a);
                checkBG(i, a);
            }
        }
        display(k);
        Sleep(DELAY);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ну и? В С++ программе должна быть функция main. Где она у вас?

Answer (score 0):

Так как это должно быть приложение, то там должна быть функция `int main(){}`. Возможно, ее роль выполняет функция go. Тогда самый простой способ - добавить ещё такую функцию

```
int main() {
  go();
  return 0;
}
```